# Get Widget size in cells in Android

Tags: android, widget, size, cell

I want to find a way to get how many cells (H x W) does my widget occupy in the home screen.

I need it so I can set the text size dynamically according to how many cells (Height and width) is the widget.
I tried to work with the formula: (N * 70)-30, but it didn't actually match the results I had.

For example, is it 1x1? 2x1? 2x2? etc...

Comment: `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` tells you the range of possible sizes, but they are in pixels IIRC. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.13/AppWidget/Resize).

Comment: N is equal to the number of rows/columns. For example, 4x2 would be (4*70)-30 x (2*70)-30

Answer (score 1):

> Starting with Android 12:
>
> We will use the targetCellWidth and targetCellHeight attributes as the
> default size of the widget.
>
> The widget’s size will be 2x2 by default. The widget can be resized
> down to 2x1 or resized up to 4x3.
>
> Android 11 and lower:
>
> We will use the minWidth and minHeight attributes to compute the
> default size of the widget.
>
> The default width = Math.ceil(80 / 30) = 3
>
> The default height = Math.ceil(80 / 50) = 2
>
> The widget’s size will be 3x2 by default. The widget can be resized
> down to 2x1 or resized up to take up the full screen.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#widget-sizing-attributes for more reference.

Comment: So they do the same thing, but it depends on the android version?